# chrome.webRequest API, Capture POST data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've just started developing a Google Chrome extension using the chrome.* API. I'm trying to analyse outgoing requests from the browser.
If I run this in my background.html:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
        function (details) {            
            if (details.method == "POST") {
                alert(JSON.stringify(details)); 
            }
        },
        { urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
    );
```

I get a notification on each request, but it seems I don't have access to http post parameters. I get these parameters with an additional content script, but isn't it possible to access the parameters through the chrome.webRequest object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible for now, you can monitor [this Chromium issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91191) for updates (click a star in the top-right corner to get email notifications).

Answer (score 6):

This is now available on the development branch of Chrome. You can access post data by checking the requestBody of a chrome.webRequest object. Google needs participants to submit their working extensions through the link below before it can be pushed into beta and eventually a stable release.

Further details are available at the URL mentioned above:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91191

And the Google developer documentation:
http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/webRequest.html