# How can I get the result of a webrequest in a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, httpwebrequest, webrequest

When I listen to all the HTTP Request with the Chrome [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) , how can I get the actual data recieved from it?

I mean if the request is made on a php page (XMLHttpRequest), how can I get the content of this page?

.

> I am now quering the data with an ajax request. But this isn't a good
>   solution.
>
> The main problem is when the request uses POST method. The data recieved from the ajax query is not the same as the data recived from the HttpRequest.

Comment: The `webRequest` API [does not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874417/chrome-webrequest-api-capture-post-data) offer a way to read the response body. Since you've mentioned that you want to intercept AJAX requests, there's a solution though. See [Scrape / eavesdrop AJAX data using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13768794/938089)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrape / eavesdrop AJAX data using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765031/scrape-eavesdrop-ajax-data-using-javascript)

Comment: Actually it's not the same problem because I would really like to get the result of the XMLHttpRequest. Why doesn't Google let us access to the response body? Is it Security issues?

Comment: There's no other way besdes the one proposed in the duplicate. The webRequest API does not allow inspection and modification of the response body because of performance concerns - Star this issue if you want to get notified of any future updates on this feature: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058#c19

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for that you can't get response body via webRequest, and what I do is try a ajax request to request the url for the second time. It's ugly, I have to request the content using background script, but It does work.

```
var get=function(url,callback){
var xmlRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlRequest.open('GET',url,true);
xmlRequest.send();

xmlRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if(xmlRequest.readyState==4){
   callback(xmlRequest.responseText);
  }
 };
};
```

you can get the response body from xmlRequest.responseText